# What is the place shown in the opening scene of Hillary's America?

Tags: film-location, hillarys-america

At the beginning of the movie "Hillary's America" the narrator walks into a visitor's center which apparently is associated with the Democratic National Committee somehow, and within this hall is shown hanging a portrait of Abraham Lincoln (the founder of the Republican Party). However, I was not able to find any DNC visitor center mentioned when I went to their web site. What is this place shown?

The alleged visitor's center or museum (?) is shown in the still image below:

[image]

Comment: This movie is a bundle of lies and propaganda; expecting facts to line up with many of its claims is futile. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hillary%27s_America:_The_Secret_History_of_the_Democratic_Party#Critical_response

Comment: Most "documentaries", especially political ones like anything Michael Moore has done, are more propaganda than fact.  I wouldn't dig too deep into the finer points of any of them.

Comment: I look at them as Fiction, or "This movie is *based* on certain events".  If you're looking for facts in a mostly fictional work, you're not going to get the answers you seek.  That's not saying the questions should be banned, but rather that the viewer needs to be aware of what he/she is watching.  I mean, should a question about the facts behind the incidents in the movie Fargo be answered?  No.  because contrary to the intro, it was a complete work of Fiction.  But you can certainly ask if a specific event depicted in a political documentary has any basis in fact.

Comment: @JohnnyBones I just want to know the shooting location. I am not trying to discover some deep metaphysical truth here.

Comment: For the record, Abraham Lincoln was a prominent early Republican, but he did not found the party. That was Horace Greeley.